# FOR loop and Array issue

Tags: javascript, livecycle-designer

I'm using Adobe Livecycle Designer ES4 to create some report. Based on XML a try to fill table. I have problem with Array. I push data into array in for loop. Below examples of my code:

1. Results - blank textbox

   ```js
   var print_data = xfa.record.containerPrintingData;
   var sfcArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       sfc = print_data.resolveNode("sfcPrintingData["+ i +"]").sfc.value;    
       sfcArray.push(sfc);  
   };

   this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();
   ```
2. Results - get all items

   ```js
   var print_data = xfa.record.containerPrintingData;
   var sfcArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       sfc = print_data.resolveNode("sfcPrintingData["+ i +"]").sfc.value;    
       sfcArray.push(sfc);
       this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();
   }
   ```
3. Results - get 2nd item x 10

   ```js
   var print_data = xfa.record.containerPrintingData;
   var sfcArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       sfc = print_data.resolveNode("sfcPrintingData[1]").sfc.value;    
       sfcArray.push(sfc);
       this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();
   }
   ```

Why 1st example don't work and 2nd work correct? I need use this array in another loops. How to solve it?

Comment: Does sfcPrintingData have exactly 10 items ?

Comment: In this example XML have 2 items, but in some cases can be max 10.

Comment: This also wokrs:

var print_data = xfa.record.containerPrintingData;
var sfcArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sfcArray.push(i);
};

this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();

Comment: You should Exactly loop til the number of available items. 
If 2 items means,
var print_data = xfa.record.containerPrintingData; var sfcArray = []; for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { sfcArray.push(i); }; this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();

Comment: Try to identify the number items and use it in the loop

Comment: I know that XML in this case have exactly two nodes. Question is why I can display all items in textbox when this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString(); is in the loop, but I can't display when this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString(); is outside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, If it has 2 items, and you looping it for 10.

What happends is, when `this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();` is inside the loop, this.rawValue gets updated 2 times. First time One item will be there. second time 2 items.
For the next iteration there is no 3rd item. So code breaks with error. But `this.rawValue` still have 2 items.

Where as, when `this.rawValue = sfcArray.toString();` is outside the loop, the code breaks  with error and `this.rawValue` don't have any items in it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. You have right. So, first I should count nodes (sfcPrintingData) and then do iteration (for loop), right? Just for sure ;)